# Iterating over hashmap in case of collision in Java

Tags: java, hashmap

Let us say we have a collision but key values are different, so by definition Hashmap will create a linked list at that bucket and add the new key value pair as the next of existing key value entry.

My question is how do we iterate over the hashmap in this case ? Does the default iteration mechanism changes to actually retrieve all the key value pairs which collided and got stored in the same bucket location ?

Comment: Iteration is iteration. I iterates over all the values, however they are stored internally. You don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

There are no changes. It would iterate over like say bucket 0 i.e. every elements in bucket and then move to bucket 1 and so on. So there are no changes in the way it would iterate.